# Spotipy audio features returns type error

Tags: python, python-3.x, spotify, spotipy

I am using Spotipy to interact with Spotify API. I have succesfully get information from an artist, its album and the tracks of each album. I can get a track id, name and popularity. However, when I try to use the audio features to get the valence, it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
for a in artists_array
    artist_search = sp.search(a,1,0,"artist")
    artist = artist_search['artists']['items'][0]
    artists.append({'name': artist['name'], 'popularity': artist['popularity']})

    albums = []
    albums_ids = []
    spotify_albums = sp.artist_albums(artist['id'], album_type='album')
    for i in range(len(spotify_albums['items'])):
        album_id = spotify_albums['items'][i]['id']
        albums_ids.append(spotify_albums['items'][i]['id'])
        album_name = spotify_albums['items'][i]['name']
        albums.append({'id': album_id,'name': album_name })

    albums_songs = []
        albumIndex = 0;
        #For each album
        for id in albums_ids:
        albums_songs.append([])
        spotify_songs = sp.album_tracks(id)
        for n in range(len(spotify_songs['items'])):
            song_id = spotify_songs['items'][n]['id']
            song_name = spotify_songs['items'][n]['name']
            song_popularity = sp.track(song_id)['popularity']
            song_valence = sp.audio_features([song_id])['valence']
            albums_songs[albumIndex].append({'id': song_id, 'name': song_name, 'album_id': id, 'popularity': song_popularity, 'valence': song_valence })
```

The problem is in:

```
 song_valence = sp.audio_features(song_id)['valence']
```

That throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spotifyAPI/server.py", line 110, in <module>
    song_valence = sp.audio_features(list_song_id[0])['valence']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I know that I have the correct song_id because it works for the popularity. The program works perfectly if I remove the valence part.

I dont understand the type error. According to spotipy I should give:

> audio_features(tracks=[])
>   Get audio features for one or multiple tracks based upon their Spotify IDs Parameters: tracks - a list of
>   track URIs, URLs or IDs, maximum: 50 ids

That is the reason why I put it like:

```
song_valence = sp.audio_features([song_id])['valence']
```

But also it doesn't work for:

```
song_valence = sp.audio_features(song_id)['valence']
```

Comment: `sp.audio_features(song_id)` is a list, so you need to give an integer index.

Comment: More specifically, you probably want something like `sp.audio_features(song_id)[0]["valence"]`.

Comment: Thanks! While you posted I also got the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! Leaving it here in case someone has the same problem. It expects a list, which can be just the song_id you want and then you need to access at index 0. Hope this helps

```
list_song_ids = [song_id]
song_valence = sp.audio_features(list_song_ids)[0]['valence']
```